# How to count duplicate values with multiple columns in Power BI by row wise

Tags: powerbi, dax, word-frequency

Consider:

[image]

I have four columns (A1, A2, A3 & A4) and I want to count the same/duplicate values in these four columns by grouping Index column.

For example, if "Index 1" has found the value in "A1" and the same value exists next to A2 column then it should remove it. If it’s not next to A1 column then it should stay. For example, "1 index" can take only one unique value in the four columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pivot and Unpivot to get this result.

Starting with a mock dataset:

[image]

I was able to transform it to this:

[image]

Here is the advanced query for your review:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZZDdCoMwDIXfpddezG3u51mKF9FJG2Zt0Anu7ZfUdWQUSs7hfIeU1lpTm8rASB5Yv6etrDmqWGNhJ5V1w0ujc4lyQ3BTxA5C+OGLCjCW/MrmCUSgdFozvbEZIXQPicP6x+5sNswjBuznOCknnfrAAQmffeS5oEtX75oa8lnkcX8wLe+0YXBM2w8=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, A1 = _t, A2 = _t, A3 = _t, A4 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"A1", type text}, {"A2", type text}, {"A3", type text}, {"A4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Value] <> null and [Value] <> ""),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Value", "ID"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Duplicates", List.Distinct(#"Removed Duplicates"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

The idea is that you will unpivot your columns so that it is possible to take advantage of 'remove duplicates' functionality.  Then pivot the dataset back to its original form.

If you want to close the gaps by shifting values to the left, you will need to do a little more work.  While the data is unpivoted, create a new index over the subgroups.  This is an intermediate level task, Curbal has a good example (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqXdSEN2k4).   Discard your 'Attribute' column from the unpivot and use your new subgroup index instead.

Here's the advanced editor for the shift:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ZZDdCoMwDIXfpddezG3u51mKF9FJG2Zt0Anu7ZfUdWQUSs7hfIeU1lpTm8rASB5Yv6etrDmqWGNhJ5V1w0ujc4lyQ3BTxA5C+OGLCjCW/MrmCUSgdFozvbEZIXQPicP6x+5sNswjBuznOCknnfrAAQmffeS5oEtX75oa8lnkcX8wLe+0YXBM2w8=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, A1 = _t, A2 = _t, A3 = _t, A4 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"A1", type text}, {"A2", type text}, {"A3", type text}, {"A4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Value] <> null and [Value] <> ""),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows", {"Value", "ID"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"ID"}, {{"Data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "AttributeRenumber", 1, 1), type table [ID=nullable number, Attribute=text, Value=text, AttributeRenumber=text]}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", {"ID", "Attribute", "Value", "AttributeRenumber"}, {"ID", "Attribute", "Value", "AttributeRenumber"}),
    #"Add Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Data",{{"AttributeRenumber", each "A" & Number.ToText(_) , type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Add Prefix",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[AttributeRenumber]), "AttributeRenumber", "Value"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"A1", "A2", "A3"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

[image]

Comment: It really helped. Thankyou for the meaningful help dear.